# How do I call a function in a class?

Tags: python, class

I try to read a text out of a text file, but when I run the code, it just skips all commands and nothing happens.

```
class mainClass:

    def __init__(self):
        filePath = input("Enter the filePath: ")
        text = mainClass.read(filePath)

    def read(self, filePath):
        text = open(filePath, mode="w+")
        string = ""
        for char in text:
            string += char
        print(string)
        return string
        f.close()`
```

Comment: `self.read(filePath)`

Comment: Do you know what a class is? Because this code looks like it was taught by a Java programmer who doesn't understand Python. There's no reason in Python to have a class solely for the point of being a "main class". Python has top-level functions which work just fine and don't require awkward hacks like in Java.

Comment: hi, yes i was a java programmer who is now trying to learn python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are opening the file in the wrong mode. "w+" stands for write (and append). You want to use "r" if you're reading

also f.close() does nothing. Code after the return statement does not run and the name of the file is text, not f. The read function (with minimal code restructuring) should be something like this

```
    def read(self, filePath):
        text = open(filePath, mode="r")
        string = ""
        for char in text:
            string += char
        print(string)
        text.close()
        return string
```

the second line in your init function should be self.read, not Mainclass.read.

```
def __init__(self):
    filePath = input("Enter the filePath: ")
    text = self.read(filePath)
```

Also you only defined a class, that's different than making a member of the class. You would want the whole file to read like this

```
class mainClass:

def __init__(self):
    filePath = input("Enter the filePath: ")
    text = self.read(filePath)

def read(self, filePath):
    text = open(filePath, mode="r")
    string = ""
    for char in text:
        string += char
    print(string)
    text.close()
    return string

test_class = mainClass()
```

Also, while this code will run, I would suggest a different method for opening and closing the file.  If you use "with"  you do not have to manually close the file

```
class mainClass:

def __init__(self):
    filePath = input("Enter the filePath: ")
    text = self.read(filePath)

def read(self, filePath):
    with open(filePath, mode="r") as text:
        string = ""
        for char in text:
            string += char
        print(string)
    return string

test_class = mainClass()
```